# How do I build a blog site with React.js that can fetch blog posts from a third party software such as Google docs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, blogs

I am building a React.js blog site with create-react-app for someone else and I want them to be able to type their blogs in Google docs, Google forms, or any other website and have it automatically update on the blog site. I've tried using services such as Zapier to connect these third party softwares to Firestore but it becomes difficult when the blog post includes special text formatting such as images, bold/italics, etc. I'm not sure how I would convert this to JSX from a third party website.

I've also looked at services such as Gatsby or Butter CMS, but most of these are either not free or require me to re-create the website entirely with a different CLI. I need something that's free for at least 75 blog posts a month.

Ideally, I would be able to allow my client to type their blog posts in a Google doc or any other document/website, and I would be able to take that content and directly post it on the blog site. Again, this includes images within the blog post, special text formatting, etc.

Comment: @Dejan.S I'm not sure if that would allow me to handle text formatting and images. Also, I'm not very experienced with Javascript, so I'm trying to find a more simple/straightforward way of doing this.

Comment: Not sure what would be more simple/straight forward then Javascript solution when you are doing React, just saying that else you would have to do a backend with python, .net ect, and that is the same/if not more complex.. From what I know there is not a "easier" solution, but I get your dilemma.